# addLevelName in python logging before a logging decorator doesn't see custom levels

Tags: python, logging, decorator

So, in main.py I have set up different logging levels:

```
logging.METRICS = logging.INFO+1
logging.TIME = logging.METRICS+1
logging.DATAPROCESSING = logging.TIME+1
...and so on
logging.addLevelName(logging.METRICS, 'METRICS')
logging.addLevelName(logging.TIME, 'TIME')
```

The decorator elsewhere in the code actually sees it (and prints it out as such level) when it is called explicitly like this:

```
@decorator(logger_level=25)
def func(args):
```

but when I call it like this it doesn't recognize it as such level and prints out that logging has no such attribute:

```
@decorator(logger_level=logging.METRICS)
def func(args):
```

My question is, why is this so? Is logging in decorator loading faster than the new attributes setup? How do I overcome this, I would really need new custom logging levels.

The decorator looks like this:

```
    def decorator(logger_level=logging.INFO):
        def timedecorator(method):
            @functools.wraps(method)
            def timed(self, *args, **kw):
                ts = time.time()
                result = method(self, *args, **kw)
                te = time.time()
                logging.getLogger('time').log(logger_level, 'time: %r  %2.2f ms', method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000)
            return result
        return timed
    return timeitdecorator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addLevelName` doesn't add the level as variable on the module level. It does put it into the level name dictionary. You should call your decorator like this: `@decorator(logger_level="METRICS")`. Also works for the built-in levels.

You also need to change the decorator a little bit:

```
level = logging._checkLevel(logger_level) // translate level string to int
logging.getLogger('time').log(level, /*other args*/)
```

Comment: I can't do that due to `level` argument in `log` takes in integers... and even though that would be a more elegant design (I am assuming that I would be doing `getattr(logging, logger_level)` or something similar) the decorator still doesn't see that level... :/